# VLC fails to play wmv files in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, vlc

I have installed vlc from the software center. In its description, it says that it plays WMV files, but when i try to play one, it doesn't play it.
The vlc window just opens for a fraction of a second and closes back. I have no problem with any other file, but wmv doesn't play.
I tried delving for good helpful solution, but nothing worked out. Finally, this was the best place to get my problem solved. I uninstall and reinstalled vlc but it din't work any good.

Comment: I had same problem with `VLC` in `Ubuntu 14.04` . and solved the problem by:
1] install last `ubuntu-restricted-extras` -> `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
2] Then upgrade `vlc` -> `sudo apt-get upgrade vlc`

Answer (score 0):

**This may work**

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted* It installs extra add-ons and plug ins for you. Also, I recommend that you go into the Ubuntu software Center, go to your VLC media player, click on the more info and install the extra add-ons for it, that may help.

Comment: nope.. doesn't work